# How to call javascript function only when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

i have tried this:

```
    function stickyheaddsadaer() {
        $("#page-header-inner").addClass("sticky");
    }

    <input type="checkbox" name="TT_sticky_header" id="TT_sticky_header_function" 
value="{TT_sticky_header}" onclick="stickyheaddsadaer()"/>
```

so when i click checkbox, it just nothing happens....

but when i try this:

```
function stickyheaddsadaer() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

then works...

can you please help me ? I need to activate javasript function by checkbox

and when the js function is actived it add class to the div

Thank you

Comment: Just check if the element "page-header-inner" exists.Can you please show what your css class sticky has

Comment: it existes, please see photo: http://prntscr.com/cu1fdy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Better to use `onchange` event and check inside function if checked or not**

```js
function stickyheaddsadaer(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){
    alert("Yes checked"); //when checked
    $("#page-header-inner").addClass("sticky");
  }else{
    alert("Not checked"); //when not checked
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="TT_sticky_header" id="TT_sticky_header_function" value="{TT_sticky_header}" onchange="stickyheaddsadaer(this)"/>
```

Comment: but i have another problem now,

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056649/why-javascript-function-inside-new-page-is-not-working

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" onclick="change()">
```

JS

```js
function change() {
    var decider = document.getElementById('switch');
    if(decider.checked){
        alert('check');
    } else {
      alert('unchecked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkFluency(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('fluency');
    if (checkbox.checked != false) {
     alert("Checkbox checked")
    }else{
     alert("Not Checked")
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkFluency()"  id="fluency" />
```

Comment: This would be much more helpful if it included a description of how it solves the question.

This also looks like it is the same as the answer by @rootleet 2 months earlier.